# Google App Engine: LinkProperty to string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

An embarrisingly simple question, which makes it all the more frustrating: how do I turn a db.LinkProperty into a string on the google app engine.

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
   link = db.LinkProperty()

m = MyModel()
m.link = db.Link("http://www.google.com/")
```

All I'd like to do is get the value of m.link. However, neither str(m.link) nor unicode(m.link) seems to do the trick.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set the property using db.Link, that should happen for you.

The following works for me though:

```
class Test(db.Model):
  link = db.LinkProperty()

t = Test()
t.link = 'http://google.com'

print str(t.link)
```

Comment: Hmm... in google's docs they say that you should do it the way I've done it. I wonder if it's wrong. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Link